# Python: How to transform every element of list according to dictionary?

Tags: python

How to transform every element of list according to dictionary?
For example:
I have list:

```
l = [0,1,2,3,2,3,1,2,0]
```

and I have a dictionary:

```
m = {0:10, 1:11, 2:12, 3:13}
```

I need to acquire list:

```
[10, 11, 12, 13, 12, 13, 11, 12, 10]
```

Comment: Did you spend any time at all looking for an existing question on this?

Comment: Yes.
And in opposite to the most answers of your link, I have duplicated keys.
Also, there is no speed test there.

Comment: 1. I said "question." 2. What difference do duplicate keys make? 3. Your results could have been an answer on an existing question, or even a comment on an answer.

Comment: 1. I search and didn't find that question. It must be because I don't think about it in terms of key/value, but in terms of map.

Comment: 2. Code like ' [v for k, v in mydict.items() if k in mykeys]' will return only values for unique keys.

Comment: 3. Thank you for your link, I added my answer there too.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to do this:

```
In[1]: l = [0,1,2,3,2,3,1,2,0]
In[2]: m = {0:10, 1:11, 2:12, 3:13}
In[3]: %timeit [m[_] for _ in l]  # list comprehension
1000000 loops, best of 3: 762 ns per loop
In[4]: %timeit map(lambda _: m[_], l)  # using 'map'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.66 µs per loop
In[5]: %timeit list(m[_] for _ in l)  # a generator expression passed to a list constructor.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.65 µs per loop
In[6]: %timeit map(m.__getitem__, l)
The slowest run took 4.01 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 853 ns per loop
In[7]: %timeit map(m.get, l)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 908 ns per loop
In[33]: from operator import itemgetter
In[34]: %timeit list(itemgetter(*l)(m))
The slowest run took 9.26 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 739 ns per loop
```

So list comprehension is the fastest way to do this.